# Is it reasonable that a downvoter should drop a comment for why the user downvoted a post?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I'm just getting annoyed by users who downvote a post without dropping a comment. It will generally help me in my mistakes on other sites, but this meta issue has been repeating and repeating over again. Especially for me, while I still don't have a high reputation to know that *whats* in other site which makes me wonder why users downvote my posts and not give a reason why.

To some who know me, I have been asking a lot of Harry Potter questions. Some of them or many have serious problems. While some of my posts are quite discouraging, because there are certain people who don't leave a comment, I really need the comment to improve each and every post especially since I'm not very well trained in English.

It's discouraging because anonymous people are downvoting, and as the asker, I don't even know what's the reason, which leaves me thinking that *I cannot improve this question anymore.*

As for my recent post which I edited with rants pertaining about this topic, I am sorry because I didn't know there is a meta site for issues here.

I am not speaking generally to all users, many users drops a comment in my post *why*, thanks for them. :)

Comment: Note that most of your downvoted question (I mean questions with negative score) are closed as either opinion-based or duplicates. Note that most of your questions have a positive score, and a lot of views. Note that your downvoted and zero-score answers are *usually* based on nothing, and one of them lacks clear reasoning and grammar. Also, note that even if there were a function to **force** users to explain their downvotes, nothing would stop them from posting stupid unrelated things, because people are sometimes stupid and irrational.

Comment: **TL;DR**: [don't take it personally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35393/should-everyone-have-to-defend-a-down-vote), [leave it be](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22934/so-annoyed-with-no-comment-vindictive-downvoting), take a deep breath, and keep posting good stuff! ;) *Don't listen to that grumpy guy below*

Comment: Note that there are 3 reasons listed for downvoting in the downvote pop-up: "*This question does not show any **research effort**; it is **unclear** or not **useful***". Some other things I can add from experience is poor use of English, rants, rape questions, and nitpicking. Obviously, posting off-topic questions will earn some downvotes too. Duplicates are often downvoted as well, so some **preliminary research** would be wise. Lastly, nothing is preventing users from downvoting because they don't like HP, LotR, or *just for lulz*. Nothing you can do about it, just put it out of your head.

Comment: @Gallifreyan: Grammar. yes, grammar. I explained above that I am a Filipino. And I am still lucky enough to express my thoughts in not-so-advanced English. Then it gets downvotes.

Comment: @Gallifreyan - More's the point, people are prone to downvote for precisely the reason that the OP has highlighted; poorly researched, badly written. Simply saying "I'm not English" isn't cause to write poorly or a shield against downvotes on a primarily English-language website. Here's an idea, why not ask someone in chat to proof your work before you post it?

Comment: If I went onto a Filipino website and posed a question in broken Filipino, would I expect to get downvotes? Yes, I would.

Comment: If a post is written in poor English, the correct thing to do is to **edit it**, not downvote it just for that reason. (Assuming it's comprehensible at all, of course.) We're supposed to judge based on question quality alone.

Comment: I'm talking about using jargon and slang, and short stuff like *thx plz ok*, and lack of punctuation. Your latest question are very well worded - they convey meaning without needless rants. Everything else we can take care of via edits.

Comment: @Valorum - So what's with the edit button guys? Is it just a display and has no reason to be put there at all? I assumed that it was also for correcting other's grammars, so you don't downvote a post that easy.

Comment: @BookStriker Yes: like I said, anyone who sees a post with bad grammar should edit it instead of downvoting it. This does happen a lot: Null, Valorum, and I, for example, all do a lot of editing to improve English in other people's posts.

Comment: @BookStriker - I think the problem here is that you seem to expect the community to make major fixes to your posts (potentially dozens of grammar errors). That can be perceived by some as laziness.

Comment: @Valorum, how about a bit of compassion here. No one is perfect and no expects perfection. But down votes for no particular reason other then how that person feels is the norm here.

Comment: @KyloRen -Well written, well-researched questions get upvotes. Poorly written, poorly-researched questions get downvotes. Sure, there's the occasional drive-by downvoter who downvotes for no good (or discernible) reason, but that's hardly the norm.

Comment: @Valorum I never said anything about *expecting the community*. Never in my entire time in posting here since my reputation's nothing.

Comment: @BookStriker - I was referring to [this comment](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10550/is-it-reasonable-that-a-downvoter-should-drop-a-comment-for-why-the-user-downvot?noredirect=1#comment31719_10550). Speaking as someone who's done [more than my fair share of edits](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/33/copy-editor?userid=20774), I can tell you that I'm still sorely tempted to downvote questions that contain poor English.

Comment: @Valorum The language of the Philippines is called Tagalog, not Filipino.

Comment: @Valorum First of all, I thought this site is as welcomed as I expected. I didn't come here to learn english, and yes, probbably if you went into a Tagalog site you might have downvoted. I went into this site for the fact that I cannot find any Tagalog sited that are specialized for HP questions, - deep HP questions, since I know how to speak English but I am not advanced. But I never expected that a little mistake in grammar can get me to a downvoted question here, which Randal'Thor explained, the content is what's important.

Comment: @BookStriker - There's a very easy solution, as I mentioned above.  Ask the chatroom to give a quick once-over before you press the "submit" button. Content is important, but that doesn't mean that good English is *un*important.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I posted a SO meta answer on the topic once. Basically, there's two kinds of "bad English" posts - the ones that are crystal clear where the user simply didn't have English proficiency; and the ones where the user simply didn't bother putting in the effort to write a quality post (no language on earth forces you to write all-lowercase, all-punctuation-lacking, wall of text rants). Typically, the difference between the two is rather clear. It's just as wrong to use the English problems with #1 to downvote, as to use the English problems with #2 to defend it against deserved DV.

Comment: @DVK Good point. To be clear, in my comments above I was referring only to type #1.

Answer (score -22):

Absolutely, But this site does not require that, so revenge down votes are common practice here.

Good luck trying to change this though.

Comment: It just really annoys me. I never knew I would face this kind of game in scifi stack exchange, well I am sure all of the sites experience this. Yes, you are quite right about they are not required, but reasonable.

Comment: I won't downvote the question, because I think it's important, but I downvoted your answer because a) it offers no solution and b) looks like whining. A good answer would be "people here are free to vote however the hell they want to, don't take it personally and try to improve your question/answer".

Comment: @Gallifreyan, so you have never been subjected to revenge down voting. Congratulations, you are the first person I know of that has not.

Comment: @Gallifreyan I just want also to ask if how can I improve my posts if I don't even know what the reason is?

Comment: @KyloRen  if you believe you've been a target for serial downvotes, post a question on this meta, sharing the source of your claim (screenshots, comments) and mods will take a look at it. [See here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6983/can-i-do-anything-about-serial-or-malicious-downvoting)

Comment: Gallifreyan is right. The real answer here is that **downvotes reflect personal taste** (only *close* votes reflect any sort of objective criteria). Requiring people to explain their downvotes would discourage a lot of people from downvoting (for fear of getting into a fight in the comments section), and **downvotes are necessary to preserve quality**. For anyone who's getting downvoted a lot (and not having those votes reversed by the system as serial voting), I suggest **examining your posts to find out what's wrong with them**, rather than whining about being targeted.

Comment: @Randal'Thor: There are certain posts that I personally believe that is already good. At first, it gets its downvotes, then rises up again. For everyone's knowledge, if this problem has already been dealt with, then in this site I shall always have a guesswork of why my posts are getting DV, remember: I am a beginner here.

Comment: It annoys me so much. You guys are have high reputations, which by any means, personally speaking, did you ever get an advice to improve your question? For instance, me, it's annoying how DV are increasing, then I examine it, then found nothing wrong, then closed it, then just be discouraged to ask again.

Comment: These comments are getting pretty long, so **I've [moved them to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52679/discussion-on-answer-by-kyloren-is-it-reasonable-that-a-downvoter-should-drop-a) - let's continue the discussion there.**

Comment: This sort of overly negative post is neither helpful to the OP, nor presents you in an especially good light, @KyloRen.

Comment: @Valorum, and I care what light I am perceived in, I think not. I have helped the OP, this site is so biased it is not funny, if you can7T see that then bad luck.

Comment: Without belittling your experience, I've had to face at least a half-dozen serial downvoters and over 50 sockpuppet accounts that were created solely for the purpose of attacking me, including one that was created by a high-rep user. The site isn't biased. Individual users are biased, the site is largely helpful, friendly and well-managed.

Comment: You state: "revenge down votes are common practice here". How do you know that? How do you know if a downvote is based on revenge?

Comment: @Wikis, I post a question in meta and I get 3 down votes seconds apart on complete different questions on the main site, and the kicker is that I have not posted a question for over a month, bujt suddenly 3 down votes.. If that is not revenge down-voting then I don't what is.

Comment: @KyloRen - I suspect it's because users have gone to have a look at your questions/answers (as you invited them to) and have decided that they're worthy of downvote.

Comment: @KyloRen - I'm not convinced that's revenge. There are other explanations, as Valorum has said. You can't possibly know people's motivations.

Comment: @KyloRen - You've invited users to go look at your posts. Some of those posts aren't great and have already had downvotes and you're acting surprised that you've had some more downvotes?

Comment: Anyway, as I said above, **commentary on this post has been moved to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52679/discussion-on-answer-by-kyloren-is-it-reasonable-that-a-downvoter-should-drop-a).** Since I can't move further comments to chat after having done so once, I'll just have to delete them.

Comment: @KyloRen - If you feel that you're being targeted, click the [Contact Us](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/contact) button and ask for a CM to review your vote history. If someone's been taking a whack at you, they'll stand out like a sore thumb. My gut instinct (looking at your post history and vote history) is that no-one's been targeting you.

Comment: You may also want to note that **the more aggressively you treat downvoters, the more unlikely they are to stick their heads over the parapet so that you can yell at them**. Although I usually explain my downvotes, there are certainly a number of users that I don't bother to, because of their history of getting upset and taking it out on whoever's stupid enough to announce themselves as a downvoter.

Comment: @Randal'Thor, so you delete my comemt that deals with the voting issue, so that I can still look like I care about voting . Good on you bud.

Comment: @KyloRen I copied that comment into the chatroom which, as I've already stated *twice*, is where further commentary on this post should be taken. I've already deleted 42 comments on this post (and it's soon to be 44). If you don't want people to see how much you care about voting, feel free to delete your own comments going on about voting.

Comment: I'm down voting this because it sounds like a whine more than anything, and is not constructive in any way or shape.