# What's the difference between [novel] and [books]?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've noticed that we have both a [novel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novel) tag and a [books](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) tag. The [novel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novel) tag has 1,008 questions, while [books](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) has 879, 32 of which overlap.

What exactly is the difference between these two tags? We aren't exactly going to deal with books that *aren't* novels here. *Is* there any difference? Should they be merged?

Comment: "*We aren't exactly going to deal with books that aren't novels here.*" - [at least 2000 questions would beg to differ](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-stories).

Comment: I wouldn't consider short stories a "book"; to me, a *book* indicates a certain length which a short story is explicitly not.

Comment: @Randal'Thor And how much of these are tagged `books`? Are you really tagging questions about short stories with `books` rather than `short-story`? "Dealing" with stuff is one thing, *tagging* is another.

Comment: The question might be conflating different things, the medium of a book and the format of a novel. Maybe clarifying when tags should denote the medium and when they should denote the format would be the basis for resolving the confusion here.

Comment: @Mithrandir Short stories often come in anthologies, which are books. What about comic books, as well?

Comment: @TARS No, I think questions about short stories are normally tagged [tag:short-stories] and *not* [tag:books]. The [tag:books] tag is probably mostly useless, since all those questions would be covered by either [tag:novel] or [tag:short-stories]. But retagging them all would involve a ton of edits, which I doubt anyone would consider worth doing.

Comment: Except any time someone asks about book series? Useful there

Answer (score 1):

Obviously there's a difference: every novel is a book, but not every book is a novel. The question is, do we need both the more general tag and the more specific one?

We've actually [been over this before](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/62/31394). I was about to close this question as a duplicate of the 7-year-old one, but maybe it's worth having this discussion again: things have changed in the last 7 years, and indeed there are a couple of newer answers to the old question which have hardly had any attention.

This is what I said in [my answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7915/31394) over there:

> ### Split [books](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) into [novel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novel) and [short-stories](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-stories).
>
> Whether or not it makes sense to have media tags at all (a discussion that seems to be still ongoing), it's undeniable that [books](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) is a broader tag than the others. We don't have a [screen](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen) tag to cover both films and TV, so why should we have a [books](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) tag to cover both novels and short stories?
>
> If we get rid of [books](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books), then our media tags become less confusing and have no overlap:
>
> - [novel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novel)
> - [short-stories](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-stories)
> - [movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie)
> - [tv](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv)
> - [comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comics)
> - [video-games](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-games)

But looking at this again now, I'd add that **this would involve so much retagging that it's probably not worth doing**. The [books](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) tag may be mostly redundant when we have both [novel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novel) and [short-stories](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-stories) (although it could still be useful for e.g. ID questions where the OP doesn't remember how long the story is), but it's not doing any *harm*. And it's certainly OK to have subtags and supertags, as for example we have tags for both [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek) and [star-trek-tng](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-tng), [star-trek-tos](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-tos), etc.

As was pointed out in comments, though (and also in [CreationEdge's answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7914/31394) on the old thread), it may be that [books](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) is being used mostly for questions about novels. In this case, the issue would be relatively easy to solve, by merging [books](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) into [novel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novel) and manually retagging those few questions which are currently tagged [books](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) but aren't about novels.

Comment: The asking about the difference was not asking about a difference between the *words* but in the way that these two tags are supposed to be used...

Comment: While you're at it, maybe solve the pluralization mess, too. ;-) At least that's done in a few seconds and without polluting the frontpage.

Comment: @TARS Indeed, but it probably needs a meta to work out which way to do it.

Comment: [Here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10550/) [are](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11547/) a [bunch](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11656/) of [questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11329/) that [were](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11273/) [back](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11685/) - [duped](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11120/). I don't see why this question should be any different.

Comment: @Randal'Thor: The problem I see with the split and then merging existing questions referencing `books` when they mean `novel` is that current usage indicates how people are understanding the tags. I think it's natural for many people to type in a tag of `book` to indicate that they know it's a book, then get chided for the tag actually being `books` (which doesn't suggest that it's something else, about the "book of the movie", etc), and going with that.